# MDC Web: mdc-select update hidden input value on change (non-native select box) | JavaScript (JS)

Tags: javascript, forms, material-design, mdc-components

Been doing well so far with MDC Web Components, but I've been hung up here for far too long. (Not strong in JS.)

mdc-select used to be non-native, then used native HTML select, and now once again it's non-native. For a while MDC Web supported a hidden input so that you could pass values to the server.

There's hardly any documentation - mostly just stuck users like me opening issues on GitHub:

Closed: [MDC Select - no longer form input compatible #2221](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/2221)

Closed: [[MDC Select] Example in README does send values to the web server #5295](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/5295)

Open: [[MDCSelect] Add hidden input element to support HTML forms #5428](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/5428)

**I need to set/update the value of a hidden input on MDCSelect change for multiple select boxes on the same page**... I can get it to do it for ONE select box, but not multiple.

Here is the select box HTML:

```
<div class="mdc-select mdc-select--outlined region-select">
  <div class="mdc-select__anchor demo-width-class">
    <i class="mdc-select__dropdown-icon"></i>
    <div id="demo-selected-text" class="mdc-select__selected-text" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-expanded="false"></div>
    <div class="mdc-notched-outline">
      <div class="mdc-notched-outline__leading"></div>
      <div class="mdc-notched-outline__notch" style="">
        <label id="outlined-label" class="mdc-floating-label" style="">Region</label>
      </div>
      <div class="mdc-notched-outline__trailing"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mdc-select__menu mdc-menu mdc-menu-surface demo-width-class">
    <ul class="mdc-list">
      <li data-value="" disabled="" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="mdc-list-item" tabindex="0"></li>
      <li data-value="north" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="mdc-list-item" tabindex="-1">North</li>
      <li data-value="east" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="mdc-list-item" tabindex="-1">East</li>
      <li data-value="south" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="mdc-list-item" tabindex="-1">South</li>
      <li data-value="west" aria-selected="false" role="option" class="mdc-list-item" tabindex="-1">West</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<!-- THIS IS THE HIDDEN INPUT THANK YOU -->
<input type="hidden" id="name2" name="input_name2" value="" class="my_mdc-select__value" />
</div>
```

I've tried targeting the hidden input with id, name, and even class. I think I need some sort of integrated function, forEach, or loop - tried adding JS beneath each select with no avail. I've worked the examples (seen below) from other users and no success. JavaScript isn't my thing, I know what it supposed to be happening but don't know the function or loop syntax etc to make this work.

I need to make sure each set/update targets the correct hidden input associated with that particular select box.

Here is my JS that works for ONE select box but not multiple:

```
// Select Menu
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';

const selectElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select'));

selectElements.forEach((selectEl) => {
  const select = new MDCSelect(selectEl);

 select.listen('MDCSelect:change', (el) => {
    const elText = el.target.querySelector(`[data-value="${select.value}"]`).innerText;

    console.log(`Selected option at index ${select.selectedIndex} with value "${select.value}" with a label of ${elText}`);

    // this works but only saves one
    document.querySelector('input.my_mdc-select__value').value = select.value;
});

});
```

Here is some code that others used that I haven't been able to modify/apply (taken from links above):

From nikolov-tmw:

```
document.querySelectorAll( '[data-mdc-auto-init="MDCSelect"]' ).forEach( function( sel ) {
    sel.My_MDCSelect__Value = sel.querySelector('input.my_mdc-select__value');
    if ( null !== sel.My_MDCSelect__Value ) {
        sel.addEventListener( 'MDCSelect:change', function( a ) {
            if ( sel.MDCSelect ) {
                sel.My_MDCSelect__Value.value = sel.MDCSelect.value;
            }
        } );
    }
} );
```

From daniel-dm:

```
<div class="mdc-select">
  ...
</div>
<input id="pet-select" type="hidden" name="pets">
<script>
  const input = document.querySelector('#pet-select');
  const select = document.querySelector('.mdc-select');
  select.addEventListener('MDCSelect:change', e => {
    input.value = e.detail.value;
  });
</script>
```

Please help! This particular issue has been open since January (people struggling long before) with no clear solution to help non-JS developers implement MDCSelect boxes. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can I ask why you are using `[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select')) `as opposed to just `document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select')`?

Comment: @I am a registered user For .mdc-button and .mdc-text-field, I had no problems with manual instantiation... but it didn't seem to work with .mdc-select. While troubleshooting I found `[].slice.call` here: [GitHub #3236](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/3236) and here: [stackoverflow mdc-textfield-working-but...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447776/mdc-textfield-working-but-switch-not-working) ...as for why? I cannot explain, glad to learn why I shouldn't be! I can try again with `document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select')`

Comment: Used this: 
`const selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select');
selectElements.forEach(selectElement => MDCSelect.attachTo(selectElement));` 

Seems to be working. Working on Rustem Gareev's answer below.

Comment: For those interested: `[].slice.call` aka `Array.prototype.slice.call` is a way to convert a `NodeList` (or any iterable for that matter) to JS `Array` instance and make use of all the useful methods of the built-in. `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
document.querySelector('input.my_mdc-select__value').value = select.value;
```

[Document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) will find the first matching element in the *whole document*, so in your loop you're always accessing the same `input` element.

Instead, you should run [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) method on the *parent element* of each hidden input, which in your loop will look like:

```
selectEl.querySelector('input.my_mdc-select__value').value = select.value;
```

Comment: Thank you Rustem Gareev! 

For those following, this works w/ manual instantiation!


`// Select Menu
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';

const selectElements = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-select');

selectElements.forEach((selectEl) => {
  const select = new MDCSelect(selectEl);

 select.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
 
 selectEl.querySelector('input.my_mdc-select__value').value = select.value;
});

});`